# Help with genius webcam

Tags: drivers, webcam

I'm trying to get my Islim 300X genius camera to work.

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:262c Pixart Imaging, Inc.
```

There are no linux drivers on the genius website.

I've run "kamoso" but it doesn't recognize the camera at all.

Also, i saw this in the syslog when plugin the camera:

```
[    6.964539] usbcore: registered new interface driver gspca_pac7302
```

How should i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that i had the cam plugged into a usb 3.0 port, because i moved it to a 2.0 port and it worked right away. I find this weird because i though you could plug 2.0 devices in 3.0 ports.
Also, if anyone is having the skype black screen problem like i did try this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1997828